# Визуальный интерфейс для SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, есть Визуальный интерфейс для SQLite(типа как у MYsql)?
Если вы знаете, напишите пожалуйста его название или ссылкой поделитесь. 
Благодарю!

**PS** Для работы над созданием сайта на PHP.
**PPS** Сайт создаю на локалке, но сразу отлаживаю на нормальном хостинге. Поэтому ищу программу по Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite Database browser 2.0

Answer (score 1):

1. Простенько смотрится, но мне нравится - **SharpPlus SQLite Developer**
   Понимает различнейшие запросы, но не суппер работать с **blob**.
2. Поинтереснее - **SQLite Expert Professional**
   Бывало, что синтаксис некоторых запросов не понимал, а **SharpPlus SQLite Developer** их нормально отрабатывал.
3. Ещё есть **SQLite Maestro** но там можно нарваться на проблемы с нормальным отображением кодировки UTF-8.

Пользуюсь в основном вторым и иногда первым.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой, дешёвый (бесплатный и открытый), который есть практисчески в любом linux-репозиторие: SQLite Browser (он же SQLite database browser)